# Getting error while inserting variable to a column of a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE A ()
IS 
NUMB_ID NUMBER

NUMB_ID:= 'SELECT 1 FROM DUAL'

INSERT INTO TAB1
(ID)
VALUES
(@NUMB_ID)

...
...
```

Getting missing expression error for this. Please help on how to insert variable to a table (Oracle 11g)

Comment: Did you mean `@NUMB_ID` or `NUMB_ID`? Perhaps the stray `@` was a typo. Also you are missing a `begin`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got the syntax, but it doesn't look like the oracle syntax at all. I suggest you have a look at some examples, there are plenty on the web. I fixed a couple of the issues, it should get you started.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE a ()
IS
  -- declaration section (after the IS or AS) 
  NUMB_ID NUMBER; --need trailing semi colon after every statement
BEGIN 
-- actual code
NUMB_ID:= 1; -- unclear if you want to assign 1 or assign a value from a table.

INSERT INTO TAB1
(ID)
VALUES
(NUMB_ID); --need trailing semi colon after every statement, the @ is not oracle syntax
  ...
END a;
```

Comment: I want to get value from a table in NUMB_ID

Comment: stack overflow is not a code writing service. With the solution I have given you so far, what have you tried and where did you get stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is all wrong.  Have you taken a look at the PL/SQL reference?

YOu declare NUMB_ID as a NUMBER, but then try to assign a string to it.

```
NUMB_ID:= 'SELECT 1 FROM DUAL'
```

Is not assigning the result of 'SELECT 1 FROM DUAL', but the actual string 'SELECT 1 FROM DUAL'.  And even if it did assign the result, since you are selecting a specific number from dual, you'd have been better off doing it correctly in the first place:

NUMB_ID:= 1;

Also note you did not include the terminating semicolon.

```
INSERT INTO TAB1
(ID)
VALUES
(@NUMB_ID)
```

Using the '@' is not how you reference an internal variable.  I will leave it as an exercise to the student to reference the *[Database PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-397990B7-9C45-4D37-A8A4-478FC116E898)* to see the proper method.